# How to set number of redirects before ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, redirect, browser

I have same service app just for admin and this app do some stuff and at the end in some situation redir to itself. It could happened for example 1000 times.

In this progress of course browser stop it and say error message ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. It's possible to set browser or something on server to raise number of redirect before this error?

PS: Sorry my broken English, please.

Comment: You don't fix that by allowing a huge number of redirects, you identify the reason your app is redirecting _in a loop_ and you fix it not to do so. Note it is not the same thing to refresh the page (js or meta redirect) compared to issuing server side redirects.

Comment: he redirects to the same page until the process is complete

Comment: Yesm as user(huge number) said, this proccess with redirecting has end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about other browsers, but in Firefox it is in `about:config`

[image: firefox redirect limit]

If you are running into the redirect limit, then I would recommend using ajax to poll the php file regularly to get the status of the process.

Comment: Nice! It's absolutely what I want! I!m so sorry I can't give you +1 vote, I don't have reputation :/